# NTFS-SSD: Testing: Write data to use whole disk Linux - overflow

Tags: hard-drive, python, ntfs, disk-space, bad-sectors

I want to **test the reliability of harddrives** (mostly SSD) to check when they break down.

(I think this question fits best on Superuser instead of stackoverflow or server fault.)

I know there are tools like `badblocks` and I am also using them.

## My test script

Additionally I am using **my own test script**, that in a nutshell **does the following**:

1. Unmounts the device
2. Formats the drive with NTFS
3. Mounts the device
4. Creates 1GB files with random data
5. Creates a file with the remaining space
6. Compares the checksums for all files

AFAIK NTFS requires 4 KB for each file created (at least it did in my tests). Maybe it is the cluster size (we are only testing <2TB).

Testing is done on Ubuntu Linux with Python / Bash:

The 1GB files are created with a ThreadPool like so:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for i in range(1, file_count + 1):
        executor.submit(_create_file_task, device, i)
```

After that, for the last file what I do in Python is (subtracting 4KB to have enough space left):

```
remaining_kb = int(shutil.disk_usage(mount_directory).free / 1024 - 4)
    result = execute_script(".write-read.sh " + device + " " + str(remaining_kb) + "K" + " " + str(i))
```

The files are written with a bash file (write-read.sh) like so (here for easier understanding with /dev/zero as not random source):

head -c $FILESIZE /dev/zero | tee $STORAGE_FILE | sha512sum > $CHECKSUM_FILE

The `execute_script` function (which is also used in the `_create_file_task` function basically just calls `subprocess.run` and pipes + decodes the output into a log file.

For the last file I sometimes (not always) receive a **tee error message, that there is no more space left on the drive** (in German: `tee: /mnt/nvme1n1p1/239.bin: Auf dem Gerät ist kein Speicherplatz mehr verfügbar`)

## What happens

As I checked that multiple times and the **overflow was always 16KB** I thought about subtracting another 16 KB changing the remaining kb calculation to:

```
remaining_kb = int(shutil.disk_usage(mount_directory).free / 1024 - 4 - 16)
```

**Why is that? Did I miss something?**

*Update:* I also tested it with this option, but the error still happens. See update at the end.

To be on the safe side I also added a **delay of 3s after the ThreadPool**, and compared the remaining space before and after the delay. But that did not change anything (as expected).

So in the last test **what happened exactly** was:

- The remaining KB where calculated as 421620KB
- `tee` again said, that there is not enough space on the drive.
- After the script finished the remaining space was `2109440 Bytes free of 256059109376B`: displayed with the following code

  ```
   disk_usage = shutil.disk_usage(mount_directory)
   logger.debug(str(disk_usage.free) + " Bytes free of " + str(disk_usage.total) + "B")
  ```
- `ll /mnt/nvme1n1p1/ | grep 239` gives me the following result (so 429633536B written = 419564 KB):

  ```
   rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  429633536 Nov 24 17:34 239.bin*
  ```
- `df /dev/nvme1n1p1` shows me the following (translated from German)

  ```
   Filesystem     1K-Blocks      Used Available Perc% Mounted on
   /dev/nvme1n1p1 250057724 250055664      2060  100% /mnt/nvme1n1p1
  ```

So the previously shown free 2109440B from shutil / 1024 match the 2060KB shown with df.

If I move the 239.bin file to another drive (free up that space on nvme1) I get the following usage

```
Filesystem     1K-Blocks      Used Available Perc% Mounted on
/dev/nvme1n1p1 250057724 249636100    421624  100% /mnt/nvme1n1p1
```

So the previously calculated remaining 421620KB + 4 = the shown 421624KB shown with df.

Now if I try to use the space directly again with the following command it again fails:

```
head -c 421620K /dev/zero | tee /mnt/nvme1n1p1/239a.bin | sha512sum > /mnt/otherdrive/239a-checksum.txt
```

### Update (using 20KB less than available space)

I also ran the script with -20KB of the remaining space:

> Creating file 239.bin with 421604KB in /mnt/nvme1n1p1
> AGAIN error message, that there is not enough space left

```
ll /mnt/nvme1n1p1/ -v
  total 249977604
  drwxrwxrwx 1 root root        368 Nov 26 20:35 ./
  drwxr-xr-x 7 root root       4096 Nov 24 09:05 ../
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1073741840 Nov 26 20:13 1.bin*
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1073741840 Nov 26 20:13 2.bin*
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1073741840 Nov 26 20:13 3.bin*
  ....
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  425533440 Nov 26 20:35 239.bin*


df | grep 1n1
  /dev/nvme1n1p1 250057724 250051660      6064  100% /mnt/nvme1n1p1
```

## Question

I assume it has to do anything with cluster size or block size or something like that, but can't figure it out. What do I need to do, to use all the remaining space? Is it even possible? Thanks!